# jQuery append() method showing Unexpexcted Illegeal token error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to insert a materialize.css code in my html through `jquery.append()` method but it keeps showing **"Unexpected Illegal token"** error.
I am confused and think it might be due to escape sequence character or backslashes ..

```js
  $(".container").append("<div class='row'>
    <div class='col s12 m12'>
      <div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>
        <div class='card-content  center-align'>
          <span class='card-title'>" + "Question" + page.id +"</span>
          <form action='#'>
            <p>"+page.question+"</p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test1' />
              <label for='test1'>"+page.option[0]+"</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test2' />
              <label for='test2'>"+page.option[1]+"</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test3' />
              <label for='test3'>"+page.option[2]+"</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test4' />
              <label for='test4'>"+page.option[3]+"</label></p>
          </form>
          <h6 id='error1'>Please select an option</h6>
        </div>
        <div class='card-action center'>
          <button class='btn' id='submit1'>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>");
```

I am using a json object and iterating through it using page variable.(JSON is working perfectly).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append content using `append()` function this way, you should concate the lines :

```
$(".container").append("<div class='row'>"+
    "<div class='col s12 m12'>"+
      "<div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>"+
        "<div class='card-content  center-align'>"+
          "<span class='card-title'>" + "Question" + page.id +"</span>"+
          "<form action='#'>"+
            "<p>"+page.question+"</p>"+
            "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test1' />"+
              "<label for='test1'>"+page.option[0]+"</label></p>"+
            "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test2' />"+
              "<label for='test2'>"+page.option[1]+"</label></p>"+
            "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test3' />"+
              "<label for='test3'>"+page.option[2]+"</label></p>"+
            "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test4' />"+
              "<label for='test4'>"+page.option[3]+"</label></p>"+
          "</form>"+
          "<h6 id='error1'>Please select an option</h6>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class='card-action center'>"+
          "<button class='btn' id='submit1'>Submit</button>"+
        "</div>"+
      "</div>"+
    "</div>"+
"</div>");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.Thank you.I realized my mistake of concatenating multiple lines in a single one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(".container").append(`<div class='row'>
    <div class='col s12 m12'>
      <div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>
        <div class='card-content  center-align'>
          <span class='card-title'>Question${page.id}</span>
          <form action='#'>
            <p>"+page.question+"</p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test1' />
              <label for='test1'>${page.option[0]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test2' />
              <label for='test2'>${page.option[1]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test3' />
              <label for='test3'>${page.option[2]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test4' />
              <label for='test4'>${page.option[3]}</label></p>
          </form>
          <h6 id='error1'>Please select an option</h6>
        </div>
        <div class='card-action center'>
          <button class='btn' id='submit1'>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`);
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

try to change `""` => ``` `` ```

In your code .. 
 `$(".container").append("<div class='row'> .. </div>");`

Should be 
 `$(".container").append(``.. </div>);`

Answer (score 1):

> **Unexpected Illegal token?**

You need to `concat` each line of html with `+` and need quoted it in `double quote`

```
$(".container").append("<div class='row'>"+
    "<div class='col s12 m12'>"+
.......
    "</div>"+
  "</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".container").append(`<div class='row'>
    <div class='col s12 m12'>
      <div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>
        <div class='card-content  center-align'>
          <span class='card-title'>Question ${page.id}</span>
          <form action='#'>
            <p>"+page.question+"</p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test1' />
              <label for='test1'>${page.option[0]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test2' />
              <label for='test2'>${page.option[1]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test3' />
              <label for='test3'>${page.option[2]}</label></p>
            <p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test4' />
              <label for='test4'>${page.option[3]}</label></p>
          </form>
          <h6 id='error1'>Please select an option</h6>
        </div>
        <div class='card-action center'>
          <button class='btn' id='submit1'>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Instead of using `double quotes` **""** please use `backtick` **``**.

And wherever you have dynamic value to be attached, please use `${}`.

`${variable_name}` replace variable_name with your variable name.

Hope this will help.